# Redirect to a page after loading it and display progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar, loading

I've seen some websites that, once you click on a link, appear to load a page before you're redirected so that the page is displayed instantly, with some sort of bar showing the progress of the request. How do they go about doing this?

Comment: Consider looking at the code for [pace](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/)

Comment: They are mostly Single Page Applications which dynamically load and render a view. Can you post a link we can have a look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using Ajax. Check out this article which shows how it's done: https://onextrapixel.com/loadingbar-js-adding-a-youtube-like-loading-bar-to-your-website/

It can also be done using the [HTML5 History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)(which is actually used by YouTube), it adds and removes page URLs into and from the History stack. The URL's from this stack is then used to load the pages using Ajax.

Read more about it here: [Curious about the new way YouTube is loading pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824909/curious-about-the-new-way-youtube-is-loading-pages)